# CSS Media Queries: How to make the right column display above the left on small screens?

Tags: css, media-queries

When resizing a window, how can I make the right column go above the left column? The default behavior is that the right column slides beneath the left.

Here's a diagram illustrating my goal:

wider window:

> ++++++++++++++++++++++++++
>
> | left column | right column |
>
> ++++++++++++++++++++++++++

and here's the CSS used to generate that layout:

## CSS

```
.left { 
  width:auto;
  overflow:hidden;
  float:none;
}
.right {
  width:500px;
  float:right
}
```

Here's what I want to display on a narrower window, like a mobile device:

> ++++++++++++++
>
> | right column |
>
> | left column |
>
> ++++++++++++++

I know media queries are the key, but I don't know the code to use. Any advice?

Comment: Add a little more code. Are your columns floated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to go about this would be using [media queries](http://css-tricks.com/css-media-queries/) and [absolute positioning](http://css-tricks.com/absolute-relative-fixed-positioining-how-do-they-differ/). [**View it on JSFiddle.**](http://jsfiddle.net/exK8N/)

Media queries, if you're unfamiliar, basically say 'apply this CSS in this particular situation.' And the absolute positioning lets us move the divs wherever we want.

In the below code, we slide our divs around when our view shrinks below 700px wide. To make the Fiddle display this, either shrink your browser window our shrink the 'Result' panel until you see the transition. (*On my computer it's significantly less laggy to slide the Result panel*)

## css

```
#left {
  background: #eee;
  height: 60px;
  width: 200px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
#right {
  background: #ddd;
  height: 60px;
  width: 200px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 200px;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 700px) {
  #left {
    background: #2f6497;
    top: 60px;
  }
  #right {
    background: #002d62;
    left: 0;
  }
}
```

Comment: its easy I know but How to make #right in top of left column?

Comment: Oh sorry @LenaQueen, I misinterpreted! I updated my answer; here's [a quick link to the new Fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/exK8N/)